# solve non-homogeneous differential systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I found this problem and I can't solve it. If anyone can help me with this  , it'd be a lot appreciated.

> Solve the following non-homogeneous system: 
>   $$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y \end{pmatrix}^{'}=\begin{pmatrix}4 &1 \\  4&-2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
> e^{-2t}\\-2e^{t} \end{pmatrix}$$

**Comments transcribed:**

The characteristic polynomial of $A = \begin{pmatrix}4 &1 \\ 4&-2 \end{pmatrix}$ and got the eigenvalues , the struggle begin with the eigenvectors. Below is what I found for the eigenvectors is it correct?
$$\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{-3-\sqrt{13}}{4}\\ 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{4}\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$
I checked their products with $A$ and it worked, but I ended up with a terrifying integral.

Comment: What  have you tried so far ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I can explain you what i tried so far so : characteristic polynomial of  $A$ = $\begin{pmatrix}4 &1 \\ 4&-2 \end{pmatrix}$   and got the eigenvalues , the struggle begin with the eigenvectors .

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{-3-\sqrt{13}}{4}\\ 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{4}\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ This is what I found for the eigenvectors is it correct , can I pursue ?

Comment: You can check for yourself whether or not those are eigenvectors of $A$. Compute their products with $A$ and see if you end up with the correct results.

Comment: I checked and it worked , but I ended up with a terrefic integral.